# Is it called the 'multiplication table' for any type of group, or only for multiplicative ones?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology

Suppose you had an additive group. Would the table showing its elements still be called the 'multiplication table'?

If not, what is the general name given to the table showing the elements of a group under a given operation?

Comment: [Cayley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table).

Answer (score 3):

You can call it Multiplication table, or Addition table if you're going by addition notion. In general you can just call it *Cayley Table*